# Python - replace unicode characters in tokenization

Tags: python, unicode, replace, nltk, tokenize

I'm using NLTK library and I want to get description of each app in play.google.com. I'm receiving right results but there is problem that are in swedish language and I need them translate to unicode but I don't know how. Here is my code:

```
for x in app_links:
    web = urlopen(x).read()
    description = re.compile(
        '<div class="show-more-content text-body" itemprop="description"> <div class=\"id-app-orig-desc\">(.*?)</div>').search(
        web)
    descriptions.append(cleanDoc(description.group(1)))

def cleanDoc(doc):
    doc = nltk.clean_html(doc)
    stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    tokens = WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(doc)
    clean = [token.lower() for token in tokens if token.lower() not in stopset and len(token) > 2]
    final = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in clean]
    return final
```

And I get i.e. this result:

```
[['aftonbladet', 'app', 'med', 'senast', 'nyheterna', 'live', 'rapport', 'push', 'notis', 'debatt', 'der', 'och', 'mycket', '
annat', 'ocks\xc3', 'sportbladet', 'med', 'vassast', 'sportkr\xc3', 'nik\xc3', 'rerna', 'och', 'jesbladet', 'med', 'full', 'k
oll', 'film', 'musik', 'och', 'spel', 'aftonbladet', 'ker', 'ocks\xc3', 'st\xc3', 'ndigt', 'efter', 'nya', 'vinklar', 'som',
'sare', 'blir', 'rf\xc3', 'viktig', 'del', 'nyhetsarbet', 'med', 'tipsa', 'kan', 'skicka', 'tip', 'bilder', 'video', 'och', '
filma', 'live', 'och', 'kan', 'dig', 'med', 'lokala', 'pushnotis', 'lsningar', 'aftonbladet', 'mobil', 'oss', 'rna', 'http',
'://', 'www', 'facebook', 'com', 'aftonbladetmobil'], ['aftonbladet', 'app', 'med', 'senast', 'nyheterna', 'live', 'rapport',
 'push', 'notis', 'debatt', 'der', 'och', 'mycket', 'annat', 'ocks\xc3', 'sportbladet', 'med', 'vassast', 'sportkr\xc3', 'nik
\xc3', 'rerna', 'och', 'jesbladet', 'med', 'full', 'koll', 'film', 'musik', 'och', 'spel', 'aftonbladet', 'ker', 'ocks\xc3',
'st\xc3', 'ndigt', 'efter', 'nya', 'vinklar', 'som', 'sare', 'blir', 'rf\xc3', 'viktig', 'del', 'nyhetsarbet', 'med', 'tipsa'
, 'kan', 'skicka', 'tip', 'bilder', 'video', 'och', 'filma', 'live', 'och', 'kan', 'dig', 'med', 'lokala', 'pushnotis', 'lsni
ngar', 'aftonbladet', 'mobil', 'oss', 'rna', 'http', '://', 'www', 'facebook', 'com', 'aftonbladetmobil']]
```

How can I change for example "ocks\xc3" to "också"? Is there in NLTK some way how to automaticaly replace it or what should I do? Thank you

Comment: could you provde the actual link you are retrieving which gives this swedish result?

Comment: Entities like \xc3 can be converted to the correct character when you output them, but the specifics depend on where you output them (e.g. file, network or terminal). However, it looks like the 'å' character is not being handled correctly somewhere. I think it should be '\xc3\xa5'.